# Java EE install through ssh on a Linux AMI

Tags: linux, redhat, java, installation, amazon-ami

I want to install Java EE 6 on a RedHat machine. The machine is actually an AWS AMI. I have installed JDK succesfully but when I try to install Java EE, the console tells me I hace to set the DISPLAY environment variable. I have googled for a while and found that Java EE can only be installed with an X server running(hence the DISPLAY variable). I have no idea how to install this as a linux AMI doesn't have a X Window environment (correct me and illustrate me if I'm wrong). How can I get through with this?

Thanks

P.D: I set the DISPLAY variable just to see what happens with no luck

```
...    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.openinstaller.core.EngineBootstrap.main(EngineBootstrap.java:208)
SEVERE INTERNAL ERROR: Can't connect to X11 window server using '10.98.135.210:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched around a bit and found another user with the same problem trying to install glassfish.

Hope this helps.

See below:
"a dummy X server will do (like xvfb http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). The following steps should do the trick for you

yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb

Xvfb :1 -ac

export DISPLAY=:1.0

After this run your executable

In case u run into problem while seeting up Xvfb, then following url has some tips for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337232/what-dummy-x-server-should-i-use-with-openoffice-on-debian"

Answer (score 0):

To install Glassfish in a headless environment, just use the .zip package, and copy the files on your server, and you can run it with the usual asadmin command line ... I had one running this way on an EC2 instance. You don't even need Xvfb or else.
Alternatively, I remeber there is a command line option with the installer which will allow you to bypass the graphical install, and have it run smoothly without ny window nor user interaction. You only need to prepare a file in advance, with a minimal set-up (including accepting the licence). I used that, until I realized the first option was much simpler ...

Comment: Are we talking about Glassfish or about Java EE 6 here?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I need to get the silent installation of glassfish working on a redhat 6.2 server. the problem is that i cant get a dry run working because of the graphical install. i already tried to work it out with xming, but it didn't work either. could you give me the answer-file? the zip is not possible for me, because i need to get the silent install working... Or do you remember the command line option to bypass the graphical install? Regards, Konstantin